# JavaScript: Object [object global] has no method

Tags: object, javascript, extend

I've seen similar questions here, but none of the solutions fixed my problem. I'm trying to extend PixiJS's BitmapText class to create a generic text object:

```
OS7.Text = function(string, x, y)
{
    PIXI.BitmapText.call(this, string, {font:"12px Chicago"});
    this.position.x = x;
    this.position.y = y;
}

OS7.Text.prototype = Object.create( PIXI.BitmapText.prototype );
OS7.Text.prototype.constructor = OS7.Text;
```

And then extend that for a simple clock that updates every second:

```
OS7.Time = function()
{
    OS7.Text.call(this, "00:00 AM", 571, 5);
    this.position.x = 571 - this.textWidth;
    this.updateTime();
    this.timeFunc = this.updateTime();
    window.setInterval(this.timeFunc, 1000);
};

OS7.Time.prototype = Object.create(OS7.Text.prototype);
OS7.Time.prototype.constructor = OS7.Time;

OS7.Time.prototype.updateTime = function()
{
    this.prevText = this.text;
    this.date = new Date();
    this.hour = this.date.getHours();
    this.minute = this.date.getMinutes();
    this.zero = "";
    this.ampm = "AM";

    if ( this.hour > 12 )
    {
        this.hour -= 12;
        this.ampm = "PM";
    }

    if ( this.hour === 0 )
    {
        this.hour = 12;
    }

    if ( this.minute < 10 )
    {
        this.zero = "0";
    }

    this.setText( this.hour + ":" + this.zero + this.minute + " " + this.ampm );

    if ( this.prevText !== this.text )
    {
        this.updateText();
    }
};
```

No matter what, I get the error `Object [object global] has no method updateText` even though that function is in `PIXI.BitmapText`. Not to mention that the whole `timeFunc` thing seems superfluous, but before that I got the error `Object [object global] has no method updateTime`.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: This was immensely helpful Felix, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
this.timeFunc = this.updateTime();
```

`timeFunc` will be `undefined`, since you are calling `updateTime`, and it doesn't return anything. Also a function called from a timer will have `window`, and not the object bound to `this`. If you want to retain the object refference, you need to use `bind`

```
this.timeFunc = this.updateTime.bind(this);
```

Comment: Yes this'd work too; it's accomplishing the same goal as a wrapper function would (well `.bind()` creates the wrapper for you).

Comment: I did `window.setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this), 1000);` since the `timeFunc` was a bit of a hack anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When your function is called on the time intervals, the value of `this` won't be the instance of your object. You'll have to wrap it in a function:

```
var self = this;
window.setInterval(function() { self.updateTime(); }, 1000);
```